# Compiling a C program using ant-contrib using cpptasks

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

This is what my `build.xml` file looks like:

```
<project name="test" xmlns:cpptasks="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib.cpptasks">
    <target name="build-native">
        <mkdir dir="/home/varun/Desktop/lucene/3018-test/check"/>
        <cpptasks:cc outtype="executable" subsystem="console" outfile="BuildNativeDir" objdir="/home/varun/Desktop/lucene/3018-test">
           <fileset file="/home/varun/Desktop/lucene/3018-test/hello.c" />
        </cpptasks:cc>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run the command `ant build-native` I get an error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/varun/Desktop/lucene/3018-test/build.xml:4: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:net.sf.antcontrib.cpptasks:cc
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/home/varun/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

But my `CLASSPATH` is set to `/usr/share/ant/lib` and I have placed the `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` in `/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cpptask` is not included in `ant-contrib-*.jar`. You have to [download](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/index.html) that separately.

I just tried `cpptasks-1.0-beta5` but it did not compile. `cpptasks-1.0-beta4` had a precompiled jar in the archive and that worked fine.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I was also successful in building `cpptasks-1.0-beta5` . I use this command `ant build-tests` and the jar gets compiled in the `/target/lib/` directory.