# How to use cpp-tasks in Ant build

Tags: hibernate, ant, open-source, ant-contrib

I am using Ant 1.8.2 And I get this error:

```
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I googled it. And realized ant-contrib is missing. After, i add ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar. But this jar not support Ant 1.8.2 And I don't know using cpp-tasks. I read http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/index.html this but i didn't overcame.

Regards.

Comment: Any idea? I couldn't use Eclipse UI.

Comment: Can you please include your build files etc?

Comment: Please list your build file... as well as why you're using ant-contrib.  there is usually a better way to do things than ant-contrib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling a C program using ant-contrib using cpptasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638149/compiling-a-c-program-using-ant-contrib-using-cpptasks)

Answer (score 0):

i thing you don't have ant-contrib  jar in your classpath.
download this jar.
and goto the window preferences in your eclipse.
select  ant-runtime-(Ant Home Entries(Default)) choose
add external jars. include the jar ant-contrib in your classpath press ok.

your build.xml should like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project name="JarCreation" default="Jar" basedir="." xmlns:ac="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">
        <property name="array" value="a,b,c,d"/>
        <target name="Jar">
        <ac:for list="${array}" param="letter">
        <sequential>
        <echo>Your Code Here</echo>
        <ac:var name="test" value="somethin"/>
        </sequential> 
        </ac:for>  
        </target>
        </project>
```

**

it will  run!